# Replacing missing value with a certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I try to fill the missing values in Critic Score by grouping 'Name'.

```
games['Rating'] = dupliacted_games.groupby('Name')['Rating'].apply(
                    lambda x: x.fillna(x.value_counts().idxmax() 
                    if x.value_counts().max() >=1 
                    else mode , inplace = False)
                  )
games['Rating'].fillna(
      dupliacted_games['Rating'].value_counts().idxmax(),inplace=True
)
```

I get this error :

> site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:6287: SettingWithCopyWarning:  A
> value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame See
> the caveats in the documentation:
> http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
> self._update_inplace(new_data)

Comment: [Please don't upload images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Update your question with the error

Comment: not an error but a warning, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an error. You have two ways:

1. Use pd.DataFrame.copy(deep=True)
2. [Turn off warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

And always think what you do with your data. Check their size(shape) after groupping, merging e.t.c.